# How does adding a constant affect the solution to a SDE

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let's suppose I have a model that described $x_t = e^{f(t) + z_t}$ however this where $dz_t = -kz_tdt+\sigma dW_t$.

Because the data I am trying to apply the model to has negative values I cannot perform a log transform to fit the model. One approach I am thinking of is just adding a constant $c$ to my data such that $y_t = x_t + c$ with $c$ such that $y_t$ is now positive for all values.

Is the solution for the SDE of $dx$ the same as the one for $dy$? can I just apply the transformation to my data, solve the problem, and then take $c$ back from the solution?

I started by applying ito to $y_t$ which has led me to

$$
dy_t = \left(\frac{df}{dt} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma ^2 -kz_t \right)x_tdt + \sigma x_tdW_t
$$

In the case of not having $c$, I can define $r_t=lnx_t$ and apply Ito again to get an SDE that gives me $dlnx_t$ and I could solve for $x_t$.

In this case, because of $c$, I cannot do that because the derivates of $lny_t$ will have $c$ in the denominator and I cannot get rid of $x_t$

Am I overcomplicating things? Is it simply the case that $dy = dx$ because $c$ drops?

Comment: Set $g(x)=x-c$, define $Y_t=g(X_t)=X_t-c$, you get by Ito$dY_t=\mu(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dW_t=\mu(Y_t+c)dt+\sigma(Y_t+c)dW_t=\tilde{\mu}(Y_t)dt+\tilde{\sigma}(Y_t)dW_t$ and $Y_0=X_0-c$ where $\tilde{\mu}(y)=\mu(y+c),\tilde{\sigma}(y)=\sigma(y+c)$ are the new drift and diffusion coefficients of $Y_t$.

Comment: @Snoop, thank you very much for your answer. Sorry, I am a bit confused. At which step you define $g(x) = x_t - c$ ?

Comment: I described the SDE of a process shifted by some $c$. If that does not help you, I would ask you to please provide more details about your problem

Comment: @Snoop thanks again. I think I am a bit confused with the notation. Here is my derivation:
$y_t=x_t+c$ then I can define $r_t = y_t-c = x_t$. From there it is easy to see that $dr_t = dx_t$ hence $dr = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 -kz_t \right)r_tdt + \sigma r_t dW_t$. Now taking $g_t = lnr_t$ and applying ito I get $dg = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} -kz_t \right)dt + \sigma dW_t$. After substituting $ln(y_t-c) - f(t) = z_t$ we get $dln(y_t-c) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + kf(t) -kln(y_t-c) \right)dt + \sigma dW_t$. 
Makes sense?

Comment: This looks **right** but the derivation is way too complicated. $\ln(y_t-c)=\ln x_t=f(t)+z_t$ and by Ito $$
d\,\ln x_t=df(t)+dz_t=f'(t)\,dt-kz_t\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t\,.
$$ In that equation you can replace 
$$
z_t=(\ln x_t)-f(t)\,.
$$

Comment: thanks @Kurt, yes agree I did complicate things a bit!